# Creating and accessing a folder with in the application for windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, directory

Can some one help me with creating and accessing folder with in the application (at the same place where we have our assets,html folders). My requirement is to download a file in that folder and then access it.

I have used:

```
StorageFolder destinationFolder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
StorageFile localFile = await destinationFolder.CreateFileAsync(localFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

when I checked it showing the path as:  `Assets folder path: C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\785bb4a5-5b27-4720-918e-7ceaeeb58c52VS.Debug..`

Answer (score 0):

If your file saved is not being for any use to end user directly then you should use App local folders. If you have very few amount of data then you can use LocalSettings also. for more available storage options and process of accessing [check this link](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/winrt-folders-access).